# ficheros csv con jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

estoy con un código muy fácil, que sólo tiene que imprimir los datos que están en un archivo csv, cuando le doy a correr, me da un mensaje de error diciéndome que el archivo no está en el directorio, cuando estoy en el mismo directorio donde están las descargas, pongo código y los pantallazos correspondientes.

```
import csv
fichero=open('people.csv','r')
lector=csv.reader(fichero)
rownum=0
for row in lector:
    if rownum==0:
        header=row
    else:
        print ('%s:%s'%(str(rownum),row))
    print ('------------')
    rownum+=1
fichero.close()


FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-1a81ef3b06f0> in <module>
      1 import csv
----> 2 fichero=open('people.csv','r')
      3 lector=csv.reader(fichero)
      4 rownum=0
      5 for row in lector:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'people.csv'
```

Y ahora los pantallazos de las descargas y del notebook donde estoy trabajando

[image: la página de descargas]

[image: el notebook de trabajo]

Si me pueden echar una mano, se lo agradecería, saludos

Comment: El código va como texto, por favor edita tu pregunta

Comment: El código va como texto, como te indican en el comentario. Adicional, si corres el paso en el notebook y ves algún mensaje de error, también puedes copiarlo y pegarlo. La captura de pantalla con el archivo al mismo nivel que el notebook, esa sí es relevante por ejemplo :) Ahí se ve que people.csv tiene 0 bytes...

Comment: Ostras, muchas gracias, no me había dado cuenta, ahora me da otro error, voy a editar esta pregunta